# Django Url Dispatcher regex

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I want SOMETHING to be non mandatory so basically I want `www.site.com/endpoint` to redirect to `www.site.com/something/endpoint` automatically. I there a way to do it on one line?

Right now I am doing:

```
url(r'^SOMETHING/endpoint$', 'endpoint', name='endpoint'),
url(r'^endpoint$', RedirectView.as_view(url='SOMETHING/endpoint')),
```

Cheers.

Comment: `url(r'^(SOMETHING/)?endpoint$', 'endpoint', name='endpoint')`? I haven't done django but worth a shot.

Comment: Can you not just do `url(r'^[.*]?endpoint$', 'endpoint', name='endpoint')` ?

Comment: This was my guess as well, but it complains that the view only wants 1 argument but is now given 2. the (SOMETHING/)? seems to become an argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this on one line? You're talking about two different URLs that do two different things—one is doing an HTTP redirect and the other is rendering a view. Two lines is the right way to go.

Writing a broader regex to cover both URLs will allow you to use the same view for both, but will not cause a redirect (that is, it will not change the URL to `SOMETHING/endpoint`).

Comment: Yeah, this is the feeling I am getting the more I think about it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking to let any url ending in "endpoint" to redirect.

To accomplish this change your redirect url regex to `r"endpoint$"`. The caret operator in regex essentially says from the start of the string.

This regex will match for any url ending in "endpoint", eg. `foo/endpoint`, `bar/endpoint`

Comment: I see what you are saying but I really want SOMETHING to be in the url as well.

Actually I feel like having it only be an endpoint might be an issue since what if i want to have an url like www.site.com/this/is/sparta/you-and-me-endpoint

Comment: @Chris Your explanation is very confusing. What is it you are trying to achieve?